# jQuery script not loading after loaded via AJAX GET call

Tags: jquery, ajax, web

I'm having a little difficulty trying to work out how to load a jQuery script after I load in a file from a jQuery AJAX GET.

This code is bound to the div id'd as navhome:

```
$('#navhome').live('click',getHome);
```

The code below is what gets the file from the server.

```
function getHome() {    
$('#pagecontent').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../../pages/home.php",
    success: postToPage});
});}
```

And this code places it on the page:

```
function postToPage(data, status) { 
$('#pagecontent').html(data);}
```

What I'm wanting to happen is to have a slider plug-in run when the file is loaded, but I'm having real difficulty understanding what I need to do to make it run.

I have the above powering a small website I made for my Minecraft Server, it's available at http://www.chernobylserver.com
. When you click on the Members page, it loads new content using the above, but when I click on Home, it does not reload the slider script.

If you're able to point me in the right direction, I would be eternally grateful to you. It's been upsetting me for a little while now. It's all new territory to me.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, I really appreciate it. :-)

Callum Kerr

Comment: So it works on one link but it doesn't work on the other one?

Comment: The slider script runs when the page is loaded, it's hardcoded into the default.php file using normal practices. When the content is reloaded using the jQuery AJAX, it doesn't re-run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just transform your nivoslider init into a function

```
 function startSlider() {
     jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider( [... options here ...] );
 }
```

and add it to postToPage();

```
   function postToPage(data, status) {  
     $('#ajaxcontent').html(data);
     $('#ajaxcontent').fadeIn('slow');
     $('#footerribbon').fadeIn('slow');
     startSlider();
   }
```

Also, quicktip: don't use .live(). Use [$.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: You Sir, are my hero. Thank you so much, it works perfectly! Just on a side note, is there any way I could place the function in the nivoJS.js file, and then call it within the ajax.js file? Thanks a million again, you're awesome!

Comment: It's kinda bad practice to do that, but yes you can do it. Just put function startSlider() {...} at the bottom of the file. Make sure you embed nivoJS.js before ajax.js file, and ajax.js will be able to call it.